# Cosa significa "dentrovi"?

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Quando, alla voltata, compare la gran mole arida del palazzo, l'ingiustizia del mio arbitrio mi sa d'amaro e mi spinge a raccogliere, come un oggetto perduto, l'oro ottobrino di Roma, *dentrovi* Artemisia chinata sulla cassa a pigiarci indumenti, suppellettili, quel che le preme al mondo, il resto lo butterà in Tevere, tanto a Roma non tornerà.

Non capisco il significato di "dentrovi" in questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo, ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Secondo quanto riporta il vocabolario Treccani alla voce *[dentro](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dentro/)*,

> (Dentro) anticam. era talvolta seguito dalla particella "vi" enclitica (**déntrovi**, cioè «**[ivi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ivi/) dentro**»): *trasse d’un armario una cassetta. Dentrovi pane, bicchieri e coltella* (Machiavelli).

Il frammento del passo citato, dunque, può esser letto come:

> [...] *lì all'interno* [cioè nel palazzo menzionato precedentemente] (si trovava) Artemisia chinata sulla cassa a pigiarci indumenti, suppellettili, quel che le preme al mondo [...]

Comment: Più avanti in questo stesso libro, appare anche il vocabolo **"sopravi"** ("in fondo al letto, da un muro all'altro, due corde stese, *sopravi* la mercanzia di Antonio"). Vedo nel [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sopra/) che si tratta della stessa idea con l'avverbio "sopra". Cioè, "sopravi" = "sopra" + particella "vi" enclitica (forma arcaica).

Comment: @Charo Chissà se nel periodo in cui *Artemisia* è stato pubblicato (1947) erano ancora comunemente usate simili forme? O forse la Banti ne era particolarmente entusiasta e poco parsimoniosa nel loro uso?

Comment: O semplicemente, dato che l'azione si situa nella prima metà del seicento, Anna Banti usava espressamente tali vocaboli per ottenere una sensazione di testo arcaico dal lettore.

Comment: @Charo Già, non ci pensavo. Direi che è perfettamente riuscita nel suo intento. :)